# Opening a file in Aptana Studio from command line

Tags: aptana3

I am learning Ruby on Rails using Michael Hartl's railstutorials webcasts. He opens files from command line using Textmate. How can we open a file from command line using Aptana Studio? What is the command and do we need to change any settings?

thanks in anticipation.